# PHP get plain text from another php file?

Tags: php

I currently tried to get the plain text from another php file line by line, however it seems that it doesnt understand the encoding.

```
  $parsedFile= file_get_contents('source.php', true);
  $text= '';

  foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $parsedFile) as $line){
    $text.= $line;
  }

  echo $parsedFile;
```

How can I extract the text from a php file by using phps in built functions and classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the built-in PHP function file() returning an array with an entry for each line, which should be exactly what you are looking for:

`$linearray = file("source.php");`

Comment: Holy crap, there is a function for everything in php. I was already scared that id have to create a byte stream and parse all the characters. I didnt really find any specifications for the php file so...

Comment: Just take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Is there any content in source.php and is this file in the same directory as the code is?

Comment: Sorry it takes a while for my question to be updated. Ill place code in here until then:    https://jsfiddle.net/kva3ok5s/

Comment: Indeed, I got a php script inside there. I do get the content as an array but I just cant access it. When doing it inside a loop the output is just empty but when accessing an item manually instead of using the $i variable it works for that one item. It is weird.

Comment: The loop just goes to 6 instead of the array count for testing purposes

Comment: I have no idea why your code doesn't work as expected, but what about a foreach loop:

Comment: `foreach($sourceFile as $line) $output .= $line;`

Comment: The funny thing is not even a foreach works. The output is empty. Ill try again though

Comment: im doing a var_dump($output) at the end. Nothing. Doing something like $sourceFile[4] works though. Never before have I encountered such weird behaviour.

Comment: Ive got some information. I fixed it. It seems that index 0 and 1 cant be used for whatever reason so I start counting from 2.

Comment: It most likely gives me something other than a true string.